# How do I display the content from a file using the function read in C?

Tags: c

I want to input text from stdin and then display it on the screen, while numbering the lines. The last part of my program is not working, I don't know how to use the `read()` function correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[201];
    int i=0, f = open("text.dat", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);
    while (fgets(s,200,stdin) != NULL)
        write(f,s,strlen(s));
    char *buf;
    while (read(f,buf,200) > 0)
        printf("%d %s", i++, *buf);
    close(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Comment: I get a weird output, it's hard to describe.

Comment: Don't describe the output. Paste it into the question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you consume `stdin`:

```
while (fgets(s,200,stdin) != NULL)
    write(f,s,strlen(s));
```

Then you attempt to read from the file `f`. However, the file `f` is already at its end, and so the first call to `read()` returns `0`. Since there is nothing to read. You would need to move the file pointer back to the beginning of the file.

But your `read()` based loop will still not do what you want. That's because you want line oriented input. So you should use `fgets` rather than `read`. Just in the same way that you handled `stdin` in a line oriented way, you need to handle your printing to `stdout`.

And as Mats points out, you never allocated buf. So if there had been anything to read, you would be de-referencing an un-initialized pointer.

Having said all of that, it would seem to me to make more sense to run just a single loop. Call `printf()` inside the loop that calls `write()`.

```
while (fgets(s,200,stdin) != NULL)
{
    write(f,s,strlen(s));
    printf("%d %s", i, s);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: `f` is obtained from `open()` instead of `fopen()`. Thus, `fseek()` may not work without a `fdopen()`.

Comment: I am supposed to work only with low-leve file processing functions, that is why I don't use fopen.

Answer (score 0):

Weird output: I would have thought that this portion would crash pretty badly:

```
char *buf;
while (read(f,buf,200) > 0)
    printf("%d %s", i++, *buf);
```

buf is not initialized to anything, and thus points "over there" (general direction of "nowhere useful"). This would cause a SIGSEGV ("Segmentation fault") in a Linux/Unix system, I would expect. You are not using a Turbo/Borland C under DOS by any chance - that's the only scenario where I could possibly imagine that this wouldn't crash. Windows wouldn't say SIGSEGV, but it would still not allow your code to work.

Of course, you may be saved by the fact that you are at the end of the file, and thus don't read anything at all.

Perhaps you meant this:

```
char buf[200];
while (read(f,buf,200) > 0) ....
```